# Is $x+1$ translated horizontally by -1 or is it translated vertically by 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation

I know that if you have $y=f(x+a)$, that shifts everything to the left by $a$ (which I tend to think of in terms that you are "tricking" the function by giving it an input that isn't actually $x$ but $x+a$. If you have $y=f(x)+a$, that  shifts everything up by $a$ (because $y$ is equal to all of the outputs, $f(x)$, increased by the $+ a$).

What I find a bit confusing is whether or not $x+1$ would be more like the first, in the sense that you are modifying the input to an identity function, or the second where you are modifying the results of an identity function.

Comment: If you plot it, you will see it is both translated by $1$ to left and by $1$ up from origin.

Comment: It's sort of weird though. When I look at it on the graph, I could see a way of making it by shifting everything left, without bothering to move everything up. But I could also do the opposite.

Because if I wouldn't actually change how the function looks, and just change it's position, moving it up automatically moves it left, and moving it left automatically moves it up.

Comment: Do one or the other. Not both at the same time. For example, let $f(x) = x + 1$ and $g(x) = x$. Then $f(x) = g(x+1) = g(x) + 1$ but $f(x) \neq g(x+1)+1$.

Comment: Almost like if you took a pencil, held it at a certain angle on lined paper, with the lines going vertically, as you move the pencil left, the point that the pencil intersects the line moves.

Comment: I feel one should mention that there are also infinitely many other ways to look at this, for instance $x+1=(x+2)-1$ so you could think of it as shifting it to the left by $2$ and then down by $1$.

Comment: And once again my attempts at rationalizing mathematics into "processes" have gone down the drain. It was nice to think there was a "reason" behind why $f(x+a)+b$ moves in certain ways, but I suppose, there is a point where "reasoning" is based on proof even if that proof doesn't make any sense or you get into weird chicken-and-the-egg scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}
y = x + 1 = \id(x+1) = \id(x) + 1
$$
The first case can be seen as $\id$ (the identity function) translated one unit to the left, the second as $\id$ translated one unit upwards. So both interpretations are fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can safely think about it both ways. it's just the way you want to interpret it.

Comment: This came out from the Low Quality review queue with an undecisive (on my personal scale) 5-2 vote in favor of deletion. Arguably it could be better as a comment, but I liked it. I let it stay for now.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you, I didn't think it was that bad, and anyway I still cannot comment, but I will learn the community habits

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Try to draw the graph of identity function $(y=x)$, and then first shift it vertically up by $1$ unit and then second time, shift it horizontally backwards by $1$ unit.

> The result is the same. Both graphs are coincident to each other.Therefore, both the ways result in the same transformation.

Answer (score 0):

When you translate $y=x$ up by $1$ unit, you are also translating it to the left hand side by $1$ unit.

It is not always like that, but in this case, moving left and moving up the graph shows two translated ones to be coincident.

Actually, it should not be considered as "I translated, so the function is added by $1$" but "I added by $1$ so that the function is translated", as the former one may mislead to some double-reasoning to your problem.

Well, consider a particular point on the function (as trying to do it in a discrete way), you may find that the new points are not coincident after the two different way of translation. It might be the real reason why you were stuck on that. But when we consider it as a whole graph, it is coincident.

Hope it helps your understanding.